# TypeError: expected bytes, pyarrow.lib.StringArray found

Tags: python, pyarrow

I want a result such as below by using pyarrow:

```
[
  {'value': 'bar', 'key': 'foo'},
  {'value': 'bar', 'key': 'foo'},
  {'value': 'bar', 'key': 'foo'}
]
```

Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
fields = [pa.array(['foo', 'foo', 'foo']), pa.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar'])]
arr = pa.StructArray.from_arrays(['key', 'value'], fields)
print(arr)
```

But I get the following error that is related to "arr = pa.StructArray.from_arrays(['key', 'value'], fields)":

```
expected bytes, pyarrow.lib.StringArray found
```

why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, I think you just swapped the arguments.

```
arr = pa.StructArray.from_arrays(fields, ['key', 'value'])
```

Also, what you call `fields` are actually instances of `pa.Array`.  There is such a thing as `pa.Field` so I found the name a little confusing.

As for that error, it is because it is looking at the second argument (which it expects to be a list of names (`bytes`)) and finding instead a list of `StringArray`.

Comment: I changed that line of code and then the result is a thing such as below:
```
-- is_valid: all not null
-- child 0 type: string
  [
    "foo",
    "foo",
    "foo"
  ]
-- child 1 type: string
  [
    "bar",
    "bar",
    "bar"
  ]```

Comment: Correct.  That is how pyarrow is going to represent the JSON you displayed in your question.  Are you actually looking to get JSON-like output from pyarrow?  Or is this struct array somehow not what you were expecting?